# When does a Pokemon get knocked out?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have plenty of Revives that would instantly heal a pokemon to half health. However, whenever I lose a fight, the pokemon will go down to 1HP and I have to use multiple potions to heal it instead.

What situations would lead to a 'knock out' and getting to use Revive instead? Is there a controllable way to do so for Pokemon that are about to lose a gym battle?

Comment: This was changed. See [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/283135/128796).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A Pokémon will faint if they lose a battle while fighting at a gym, or if they get kicked out while defending at a gym.

If you get too many revives you can always dump them to make more room to hold other things.

Comment: This is correct. I didn't even realise you could battle until I got one.