# Has there been a change to the health of Pokémon returning from arenas?

Tags: pokemon-go

Based on my previous experience and [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274009/when-does-a-pokemon-get-knocked-out), Pokémon that you left in friendly arenas that got beaten would return to you with 1 hp, thus allowing to heal them directly with potions.

However, today, the two Pokémon that I left in a friendly arena returned to me after some time with **0 hp**, which means that I now need revives before healing them.

Has there been any word from Niantic / any external confirmation that this mechanic has been changed, and that now beaten Pokémon always come back to you with 0 hp?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, Niantic released 1.05 for iOS and 0.35 for Android that implemented this change.

> Fixed a bug that kept defeated Pokémon at 1HP; these Pokémon will now return as fainted Pokémon. We’re working on rebalancing the training battle, stay tuned.

Source: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nianticlabs.pokemongo&hl=en

Comment: Well, now I have to stop throwing away my revives to make room…

Comment: I feel like everyone is thinking the same thing.